# An easy way to validate an XML against a C# Class

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, deserialization, xml-validation

I use the XML format to keep settings for my C# project.
Theses XMLs are deserialized into C# classes.

Often enough, a class design changes but I forget to update the XML. Deserialization usually works fine and missing elements just get their default values.

This behavior is not desirable for me. **I would like to have automatic validation that asserts the class and the XML have exactly the same structure.**

I know I can create XML schemas (e.g using XSD) for my classes, but I could not figure an easy way to do it automatically and not manually (recall my classes' design changes often). Also, this solution seems kind of unnatural. I do not really need XML schemas. I have classes and their serialized XML instances. Adding schemas seems superfluous.

Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't create a method in your settings class that can be invoked after xml deserialization?

Suppose you have a class like this:

```
class Settings {
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    public int Property2 { get; set; }

    public bool IsValid() {
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Property1)) return false;
        if(Property2 == 0) return false;
    }
}
```

Using **IsValid** you can check everything in your class. Please, remember that this is an example. I think is good to manage object validation. If you change something in the time, you can edit the validation method to check new situations.

Answer (score 0):

To go with Roberto's idea and take it a step further you could get all the properties via reflection:

```
var props = yourClass.GetType().GetProperties()
```

Inside of your validation function you could loop over those properties with:

```
foreach(var prop in props) // or foreach(var prop in yourClass.GetType().GetProperties())
{
   //...Validation of property
}
```

If one of the properties has its standard-value you throw a custom exception that tells you you did not update your XML-file properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this using Version Tolerant Serialization (VTS) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229752%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

The Serialization Callbacks is what you are looking for in the VTS capabilities